# Why didn’t they just use the transporter on Krall?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

Towards the end of the movie Star Trek Beyond we see

> the evil captain using gravitational drift and jumping towards the centre of Yorktown. Kirk tells this to everyone and follows him into the gravitational force thing.

However:

> Yorktown has transporters. So in theory, someone could track the evil captain and beam him to the station's jail.

**Why didn’t they just use the transporter on Krall?**

Comment: Biggest plot hole I've had pointed out thus far. +1

Comment: The transporters are being installed next tuesday

Comment: @Valorum not really. Towards the beginning of the movie you can see, that transporters are widely available to the public

Comment: @PavelJanicek It's a joke, or rather it is a quote from *Star Trek VII* or as it was apparently called: *Star Trek: Generations*, where they at least bothered with an explanation with why the usual solutions wouldn't work then...

Comment: I had the same question. Perhaps the strange gravity at that spot affected the targeting? @PavelJanicek True, they have public transporters, but I don't recall ever seeing point-to-point transporting in the Kelvin timeline, always pad-to-point, point-to-pad, or pad-to-pad. The public pads may work like public transit where you can only go from stop to stop (just conjecture) in order to prevent transporter accidents.

Comment: @PavelJanicek - Or maybe the jail is like the one in Support Your Local Sheriff, where they had to send away for the bars and doors.

Comment: @PavelJanicek You failed to consider the timeline distortions caused by the interflux chroniton capacitors of the Krall Swarm Ships.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most likely explanation seems to be that transporters are actively blocked from working in the core because of the potential for causing damage to systems that are vital to the Station's life support.

> **Kirk:** *Mr Scott. Why's it [the core] still functional?*
>
> **Scott:** *I'm working on that Sir, but there are a **bunch of security protocols for a system which keeps everybody alive.***

This would also explain why Krall can't just beam in *and* why the Franklin can't target him.